# Tabulator throws error when adding an empty row with datetime formatter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have the following code (just a button, one column and one row)

```
    <div class='btn-toolbar'>
        <button id='new' class='btn buttons m-2 mdi mdi-plus' onclick="NewClick()" type="button">New</button>
    </div>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
<script>
    // Tabulator

    var tblTestTabelle_40028804 = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height: "311px", selectable:true, 
        "data": [
            {
                "1A27078D-D7D4-434E-AD90-D825276756FC": "06.03.2021",
                "id": "3432938F-A7AB-4F12-B756-E645093D4439"
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "title": "Date",
                "field": "1A27078D-D7D4-434E-AD90-D825276756FC",
                "formatter": "datetime", formatterParams:{
                    inputFormat:"dd.MM.yyyy",
                    outputFormat:"DD",
                    invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)",
                }
                
            }
        ],
        layout: "fitData"

    });
    //basic functionality
    function NewClick() { tblTestTabelle_40028804.addRow(); };
</script>
```

When I click the NewButton I get the following JS exception:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: fromFormat requires an input string and a format` (in luxon.min.js)
It sounds to me like a bug in tabulator, that the datetime formatter isn't able to handle adding empty rows, but maybe I'm wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the v5.0 release that has been fixed as of v5.1